# Using Cron/Python

Tags: cron, python

I was wondering if my crontab jobs were written correctly. I am hoping to run them on a VPS and monitoring them isn't really possible. Without further ado here are my cron jobs:

```
# cd into directory at 2:57 AM 
57 2 * * 1-5 cd /folder_name

# activate the virtual environment
58 2 * * 1-5 . env/bin/activate

# run the main script
59 2 * * 1-5 python main.py

# at 5pm break the script (worried the most about this part)
0 16 * * 1-5 ^C
```

Also I changed my system clock to be eastern time, does that mean the cron jobs will run using the eastern time zone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `cron` is not a shell.  Write a script:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /folder_name
. env/bin/activate
exec python main.py
```

Make it executable, then point a `crontab` entry to it:

```
57 2 * * 1-5 /path/to/script
```

The script should then run every Monday to Friday, at 2:57 in (your machine's idea of) local timezone.  If you configured your mail system properly the results (if any) are mailed to you.

Comment: Just curious, but if I added: `0 16 * * 1-5 /usr/bin/sh killall -9 main.py` to my crontab would that stop my python script (also do I have to specify where main.py is, like /folder_name/main.py)

Comment: @ng150716 Does that command work if you run it from a terminal? If it doesn't, why not? (Rhetorical questions, you don't need to post the answers).

Answer (score 0):

Your cron jobs are not written correctly.  Every cron job gets its own environment, which means the `cd` command has no bearing on the following cronjobs.

As far as virtual environments, I suggest you manually activate the virtual environment, and then run `which python` yourself.  That will give you a full path to a `python` that will always run in that virtual environment.  You should use this python path in your cron.

Final crontab should look something like this:

```
0 3 * * 1-5 /full/path/to/virtualenv/python /full/path/to/main.py
```

As far as killing the process later, the most common solution to this problem is by using a pidfile.  There are python libraries to help you do this.  [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/789383/5750032) is fairly thorough on that subject, but is not really related to the crontab question.

Comment: How about: `0 16 * * 1-5 /usr/bin/sh killall -9 main.py`? Would that stop my python script (also do I have to specify where main.py is, like /folder_name/main.py)

Comment: I am not sure, but I don't think so.  I am fairly sure the process will be `python`.  You also run the risk of killing other tasks run by python (or called `main.py` if your way happens to work).